# How do I return to user input after completing one path of a conditional in java?

Tags: java, user-input

I'm rather new to programming, so I'm not quite sure how to phrase my question:

I'm trying to make a sort of "help command" in my program that will work as follows: 
If, after being prompted for input, the user inputs the necessary string, the program will print out a list of accepted commands into the terminal window. **After completing this, I want the program to then return to the point where the user was prompted for input (i.e. where they initially entered "help").** I haven't been able to research this problem at all, as I don't even know what search terms to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using what is referred to as "recursion." ([Learn about recursion here!](http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html))

Here is an example of one way to do what you are asking, and how it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    handleInput(scanner);
}

public static void handleInput(Scanner scanner)
{
    System.out.println("Please input a command: ");
    boolean quitting = false;
    if(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("help"))
        {
            System.out.println("This is the help menu!");
        }
        else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
        {
            System.out.println("Quitting!");
            quitting = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("I did not understand that command. Say 'help' for help.");
        }
    }

    if(!quitting)
        handleInput(scanner);
    else 
        scanner.close();
}
```

The way this code works is that first a new `Scanner` is created which is then passed into a method called `handleInput`. Inside `handleInput`, we first print out a prompt for the user to input something, then call `scanner.hasNextLine()` which will block, or stop, the program until the user inputs something and presses enter.

Once we receive input, we check if the input matched any of our commands using an if-statement. If they said "help," then we print out our help menu. If they said "quit," we will set the variable `quitting` to `true` (This will be handy in a moment). And if they said anything else, we tell them we don't recognize the command.

After we do all this, we have one more if-statement at the end of the method. This statement evaluates whether or not `quitting` is `true`. If `quitting` is `false`, then we will call the `handleInput` method again; this is the recursion part of the program. From the tutorial I linked to at the top of the page, it is said that, "Simply put, recursion is when a function calls itself." That is what we are doing here. `handleInput` is calling itself, essentially creating a loop. If however `quitting` is `true`, signifying that the user wants to quit, we do not call the method again and instead close the scanner and let the method end. The `main` method will then continue, and since there are no more instructions after `handleInput(scanner);` the program exits.

If you have any confusion about this, post a comment and I will be happy to help!

Comment: It's fine. As long as there is no [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) :) [*See also.*](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/194646/103038)

Comment: @ADTC Right, I understand the stack overflow concept, but I believe in this case it wouldn't occur. It is probably better to use a while loop instead of recursion, but I wanted to provide an alternative solution for OP.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will help me a lot. I'm planning to have the commands listed in help call objects,

Comment: ^Accidentally hit enter^ Meant to say: Thanks, this looks like it will help me a lot. Also, I'm planning to have the commands listed in help call objects when inputted. will I be able to integrate object oriented code into this? Also, do you think this can be adapted to handle improper input? (I just want to know if you think it's possible since, if it is, I'd like to try figuring it out myself.)

Comment: @MataoGearsky You could change if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) to something like if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("help") | input.equalsIgnoreCase("hepl")) to account for spelling mistakes (just use OR operators to add multiple definitions of "help"). And yes, you should be able to integrate object oriented code into this, but "object oriented code" is pretty broad. If you make a new question showing sample code and what you are trying to accomplish, I'm sure someone could help you do it!

Answer (score 0):

You write a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) (or two). Something like

```
public static String getMenu() {
    return "1. Please continue to hold";
}

public static void printMenu() {
    System.out.println(getMenu());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
            printMenu();
        } else {
            System.out.println("? " + line);
        }
    }
}
```